# IE8 not applying CSS altough files are loaded and classes added to DOM objects

Tags: css, internet-explorer, styles, render

I'm having some trouble with our precious Internet Explorer 8. We are working on a CMS for hotels and everything was just fine until awhile back, when IE8 stopped rendering the frontend properly. This is [the public website demo](http://hotel.xandercms.com/en/home/) and the top navigation as well as the menustrip are messed up in IE8. Same with the "Payment methods" in the right side of the footer, where small icons for accepted payment methods should have been shown.

The thing is, we do have a special CSS file dealing with IE issues and it's loaded on the website, but it's not being applied to elements by IE. Also, on my local machine other CSS files (not conditional) are being loaded in IE, but the browser doesn't apply the styles.

It's like this:

- the CSS file is loaded
- the classes are applied to the tags
- but the styles are not applied to those classes (!)

Now this behaviour happens on some pages and doesn't happen on others (very few). For example, on [this page](http://hotel.xandercms.com/en/rooms/) the menustrip is ok. I read about similar issues in [IE isn't rendering the CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989737/ie-isnt-rendering-the-css) and [js dom injected elements don't pick up CSS styling in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424617/javascript-dom-injected-elements-dont-pick-up-css-styling-in-ie). The thing is this behaviour has been reproduced on other PC's in the office, as well as at home. I'm quite baffled by this.

Has anyone else experienced similar issues? If so, did you fix it? How did you manage to fix it? Thanks to all!

Comment: Have you looked at it using developer tools?  Also, check out the [quirks mode setting](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/internet-explorer-and-quirks-mode/).

Comment: The strange thing i see on IE8 is footer. It has open tag `<footer/>` which is not right and maybe that's why styles are not applied. Top menu looks ok to me.

Comment: @Westie I tried using the developer tools (unfriendly as they are) and Quirks Mode, but nothing helped so far.

Comment: @Morpheus If you look at the source (right click > view source) you'll see the tag is closed properly. If you look with developer tools, you'll see that none of the tags are closed because that's just how developer tools shows them.